# Propositional Logic - Converting a WFF into CNF

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I tried to solve the following question, but I don't know if my solution is correct!

**Q:** Transform the following proposition into conjunction normal form (CNF):

```
( ∧ ) ∨ ( ∧ ) ∨ ( → )
```

**A:** Let P ≡ The Whole Proposition, 1 ≡ ( ∧ ), 2 ≡ ( ∧ ), and 3 ≡ ( → )

```
≡ ¬¬( ( ∧ ) ∨ ( ∧ ) ∨ ( → ) )                [Negation Law (P)]
≡ ¬¬( ( ∧ ) ∨ ( ∧ ) ∨ (¬ ∨ ) )               [Material Implication Law (3)]
≡ ¬ ( (¬ ∨ ¬) ∧ (¬ ∨ ¬) ∧ ( ∧ ¬) )           [De Morgan Law (P)]
≡ ¬ ( (¬ ∨ ¬) ∧ (¬ ∨ ¬) ∧ ¬¬( ∧ ¬) )         [Negation Law (3)]
≡ ¬ ( (¬ ∨ ¬) ∧ (¬ ∨ ¬) ∧ ¬(¬ ∨ ) )          [De Morgan Law (3)]
≡ CNF
```

**UPDATE**

The correct answer is as follow:

```
   ( ∧ ) ∨ ( ∧ ) ∨ ( → )

≡  ( ∧ ) ∨ ( ∧ ) ∨ (¬ ∨ )                          [Material Implication Law]

≡  [( ∧ ) ∨ ] ∧ [( ∧ ) ∨ ] ∨ (¬ ∨ )              [Distribution Law]

≡  ( ∨ ) ∧ ( ∨ ) ∧ (( ∨ ) ∧ ( ∨ ) ∨ (¬ ∨ )    [Distribution Law]

≡  ( ∨ ) ∧ ( ∨ ) ∧ ( ∨ ) ∧ ( ∨  ∨ ¬ ∨ )       [Associative Law]

≡  CNF
```

Thanks to (@Bram28).

Comment: That's not in CNF -- a CNF must have all the conjunction as the _topmost_ logical connective; you have them all beneath a negation.

Comment: If not, would you please show me how to solve it then? @HenningMakholm

Comment: Don't negate; distribute

Comment: Would you be more specific? @GrahamKemp

Comment: @Badger Bram28 has it covered.  Give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

The equivalence rule you want to use is

**Distribution**

$P \lor (Q \land R) \Leftrightarrow (P \lor Q) \land (P \lor R)$

Using this you can turn disjunctions of conjunctions into conjunctions of disjunctions, which is what you want to do to get things into CNF.

Comment: Also $\rm ~(S\wedge T)\vee(U\wedge V) ~\iff~ (S\vee U)\wedge(S\vee V)\wedge(T\vee U)\wedge(T\vee V)~$ and so on.

Comment: yes, the good old FOIL works here as well!

Comment: I tried that before, but the last proposition with an arrow couldn't figure it out!

Comment: @Bader  Rewrite the conditional as a disjunction, which is what you did already.  And then know that if you have something like $(A \land B) \lor C \lor D$, you should treat the $C \lor D$ as one claim when doing distribution, so you get: $(A \land B) \lor C \lor D \Leftrightarrow (A \land B) \lor (C \lor D) \Leftrightarrow  (A \lor (C \lor D)) \land  (B \lor (C \lor D)) \Leftrightarrow  (A \lor C \lor D) \land  (B \lor C \lor D)$.

Comment: Ohhh, I see!! The answer was in front of my eyes all the time but I guess I made it look rather complicated. Thanks @Bram28